# Should Vinyl Fencing be attached to the house?

Tags: fence, vinyl

My neighbor wants to replace our current fence which we are fine with. However, the previous fence appears to be attached to the house by a lag bolt into a stud behind the stucco.

My wife and I would like to fill the holes and have the new fence not be attached directly to our house. We don't want any potential water damage, insect invitations, or extra stress put on our house due to wind or anything of that nature.

Are we being overdramatic? This is our forever home so we would like to avoid any problems that we can!

[image: Photo of current fence]

Comment: The existing fence seems to have been there for a number of years. Are there any signs of the type of damage you're concerned about? If not, what leads you to believe that this damage will suddenly happen by installing a new fence? Attaching the end of the fence to the structure will significantly reduce the work effort in digging and planting a post right next to the house (potentially encountering the foundation/footing, utility lines, etc.).

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any current damage. Admittedly this is partially due to my father in law freaking out and my wife coming from a very traditional Chinese family. So we are showing extra concern out of respect for him.

Comment: That's a fair and reasonable thing to do then! Take a stroll around the neighborhood, look at other fences, if you find a number connected to houses as yours is, show your FIL - it may help ease his concerns by showing him that this is a common construction method.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you are fine with any damage the new fence does by banging against your house there's no need to attach it.

Also digging post foundations close to your house foundation may be tricky if you encounter buried services.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with you OP.   Forget that screwing stuff to your house.  They can dig a single post hole, won't kill 'em.   How deep do you gotta go?  I see what looks like a palm tree so you don't have to go 48" like I do here in the north!

If you don't wanna force the issue, at least make them leave an air-gap between the fence and the house via some spacers... let it breath so it doesn't trap water

Comment: The sight of a palm tree should say warm place, but not 100%.  Just read a story about Nova Scotia of some palm trees they planted a few years ago.